# How to close a Alert dialog after a await is completed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
 updateDetails() async{  
           showDialog(   
              context: context,  
              builder: (BuildContext ctxt) {  
                return Container(  
                  child: AlertDialog(   
                    content: Row(   
                      children: [  
                        Container(  
                          child: Text("Updating profile..."),  
                        ),  
                        CircularProgressIndicator(),  
                      ],  
                    ),  
                  ),  
                );  
              });  
    await updateDetails();  
    //NOW I HAVE TO CLOSE THIS DIALOG  
    }
```

Comment: Where you define `updateDetails` method?

Comment: On another dart file

Comment: Are you close alert dialogue automatically?

Comment: @Kiransreeram please show us your button `onPressed` code .

Comment: Yes @ravindra S. patil

Comment: @Kiransreeram please check my answer hope it help to you

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope it help to you in below code I have add **Future.delayed** function it use is future that runs its computation after a delay.(your alert close autometically after 5 secodns)

```
 showAlert() {
  showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 5),
      () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
      },
    );

    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Title Here'),
      content: Text('Data'),
    );
  },
 );
}
```

Note: Change seconds on your need

Answer (score 0):

When your loading of data is complete you have to call following code:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Note: You should add `return` in front of showDialog for await to work.

Edit:
If you are calling showDialog inside button press event, you can try following code:

```
showDialog();
await updateDetails();
Navigator.pop(context);
```

This will pop your dialog once update is complete.

Comment: I was using this show dialog inside a button on pressed, so Future cannot be returned

Answer (score 0):

I passed the BuildContext of the AlertDialog to a dynamic variable, then used it to pop the BuildContext after the Future function.

Example using your code:

```
     updateDetails() async{

       //added this dynamic variable
       dynamic context_to_pop;

       showDialog(   
          context: context,  
          builder: (BuildContext ctxt) {

            //assigned the context to my variable
            context_to_pop = cxtx;

            return Container(  
              child: AlertDialog(   
                content: Row(   
                  children: [  
                    Container(  
                      child: Text("Updating profile..."),  
                    ),  
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),  
                  ],  
                ),  
              ),  
            );  
          });  
  await updateDetails();  

  //and used it to pop the dialog when updateDetails() is done
  Navigator.of(context_to_pop).pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start(BuildContext context) async {
try {
  BuildContext? dialogContext = null;

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      dialogContext = context;
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Container(
          height: 50,
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ).then((o) {
    dialogContext = null;
  });

  final file = File(savePath);
  final sink = file.openWrite();

  _getAudio().listen((data) {
    sink.add(data);
  }, onError: (e) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())),
    );
  }, onDone: () {
    sink.close();
    if (dialogContext != null) {
      Navigator.of(dialogContext!).pop();
    }
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text("ok")),
    );
  });
} catch (e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Android Studio warning when doing all of the previous answers:

> Don't use BuildContext's across async gaps.

If you still want to do so, make sure to check if context is still mounted before using it as the user may have clicked outside the dialog when using it:

> if (context.mounted)

[image: Don't use BuildContext's across async gaps]

Documentation: https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/use_build_context_synchronously